# prove that If |A|>4 Then |(A)|+|(B)| ≠ |(A∪B)|

Tags: discrete-mathematics

hello i need help to prove that this statement is either true or false . i already tried to prove it with an example and arrived to the conclusion that this statement is true .
my question is how can i prove that it is true or false for any  given set  without a specific example .
If |A|>4 Then |(A)|+|(B)| ≠ |(A∪B)|.

p.s: (A) and (B) are power sets

Comment: Here $P(A)$ means the set of all subsets of $A$?

Comment: As your question is asked, it is very incomplete : if $P(.)$ means probability, you have forgotten to write down most hypotheses : you have set of $n$ elements endowed with uniform probability but this is not enough, what is $B$, etc.

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion first time posting. Here P(A) = means powerset of A and P(B) is powerset of B. We have no information regarding the set B.

Comment: Assuming $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, this is true if $|A|>1.$ Without that assumption, you can always choose $B$ with $|B|=|A|$ and $|B\cap A|=|A|-1.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Hint: under what circumstances do there exist integers $a,b, c$ such that $2^a+2^b=2^c$?

Comment: thanks for the hint.